# MediaPlayer:java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC

Tags: android, media-player

i  used MediaPlayer on  a dialog:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private static final String TAG = "AudioRecorder";
ImageView showImageview;
Button recordBn;
Button playBn;
Button confirmBn;
Dialog dialog;
Boolean isRecord;
Boolean isCancel;

 private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
 private File file;
 private static final String OUT_FILE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/myshine.amr";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.file = new File(OUT_FILE_NAME);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             dialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    R.style.MyDialog);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.record_dialog);

             isRecord=false;
            showImageview=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.show_image);
            recordBn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_record);
            playBn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_play);
            confirmBn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_cancel);

            recordBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isRecord = !isRecord;
                    if (file.exists()){
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (isRecord) {
                            isCancel=true;
                            recordBn.setText(R.string.stop_record);
                            playBn.setEnabled(false);
                            playBn.setText(R.string.paly_voice);
                            confirmBn.setText(R.string.cancel);
                            record(null);

                     }else{

                            isCancel=false;
                            recordBn.setText(R.string.record);
                            playBn.setEnabled(true);
                            playBn.setText(R.string.paly_voice);
                            confirmBn.setText(R.string.confirm);
                            //结束录音
                            stop(null);

                            //初始化播放

                     }

               }
          });



playBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //If the track is playing, pause and achange playButton text to "Play"
                        play(null);
//                      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
//                      {
//                          mediaPlayer.pause();
//                          playBn.setText(R.string.paly_voice);
//                           Log.i(TAG, "playing");
//                      }
//                      //If the track is not player, play the track and change the play button to "Pause"
//                      else
//                      {
//                          mediaPlayer.start();
//                          playBn.setText(R.string.pause_voice);
//                          Log.i(TAG, "play");
//                      }
                    }
                });

            confirmBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isCancel = !isCancel;
                     if (!isCancel) {
                            //取消 结束录音
                            stop(null);
                            Log.i(TAG, "endcancel");
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }else {
                             stop(null);
                             dialog.dismiss();
                             Log.i(TAG, "send");

                        }
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}





 public void record(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "record");
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
//        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
        this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.file.getAbsolutePath());
//        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        try {
            this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
            this.mediaRecorder.start();

            // update the buttons

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to record()", e);
        }
    }


    public void stop(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "stop()");
        if (this.mediaPlayer != null) {
            // stop/release the media player
            this.mediaPlayer.stop();
            this.mediaPlayer.release();
            this.mediaPlayer = null;
        } 
        if (this.mediaRecorder != null) {
            // stop/release the media recorder
            this.mediaRecorder.stop();
            this.mediaRecorder.release();
            this.mediaRecorder = null;
        }

    }

public void play(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "play()");
    Log.d(TAG, "ddd:"+this.file.getAbsolutePath());
    if (this.file.exists()) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.file.getAbsolutePath());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     playBn.setText(R.string.pause_voice);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to play()", e);
       }
    }

}

}
```

It give me :

```
01-28 13:58:11.803: E/MediaPlayer(31717): error (-4, -4)
01-28 13:58:11.813: E/AudioRecorder(31717): Failed to play()
01-28 13:58:11.813: E/AudioRecorder(31717): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC


   01-28 14:13:39.038: D/AudioRecorder(32641): record
   01-28 14:13:39.038: D/MediaRecorder(32641): doCleanUp
    01-28 14:13:43.042: D/AudioRecorder(32641): stop()
    01-28 14:13:43.042: D/MediaRecorder(32641): stop:E
    01-28 14:13:43.392: D/MediaRecorder(32641): doCleanUp
    01-28 14:13:43.392: D/MediaRecorder(32641): stop:X
    01-28 14:13:43.392: D/MediaRecorder(32641): release:E
    01-28 14:13:43.432: W/MediaRecorder(32641): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
     01-28 14:13:43.432: W/MediaRecorder(32641): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
    01-28 14:13:47.296: D/AudioRecorder(32641): play()
    01-28 14:13:47.296: D/AudioRecorder(32641): ddd:/mnt/sdcard/myshine.amr

   01-28 14:13:47.356: E/MediaPlayer(32641): error (-4, -4)
    01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641): Failed to play()
    01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC
    01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at   com.example.customdialogrecord.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.java:200)
   01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):  at com.example.customdialogrecord.MainActivity$1$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:106)
    01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
   01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
01-28 14:13:47.356: E/AudioRecorder(32641):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can see i add the  if (this.file.exists())

Comment: you can download the app project http://dl.iteye.com/topics/download/73043b87-c3b7-3722-8faf-e03684b68932

Comment: When launching the app itself it shows this error???Or after performing some actions??